# How to create checkboxes and radiobuttons with only html and css

Tags: html, css

I'm currently working on a school-project where a big part of my idea is based on radio-buttons and checkboxes. I've found a lot of codes out there on how to create them, the only problem is that I'm only allowed to use certain html-tags and no jQuery.

The tags I can use:

• html, head, body, title, meta, link

• header, section, article, footer

• div

• h1-h6

• p

• span

• ul, ol, li

• a

• img

• audio

Is there any way to create checkboxes and radio-buttons with these tags?

Comment: Not unless they are only for show - see my answer.

Comment: I'd recommend updating the question with what you are trying to achieve in a more general sense, as it's unlikely that radio/checkbox buttons are the answer if you are not allowed to use the `input` element

Comment: What is it you're actually trying to achieve?

Comment: They need to work or it's just a visual exercise?

Comment: Update:

I understand that I can not create checkboxes and radio-buttons without using input or jQuery.

What I'm trying to achieve is having small boxes (or circles) that the user can click on, and after click it looks selected. I guess I could achieve this with the :target selector in css. The only "problem" is that if the user chooses another circle, the first circle chosen wouldn't go back to be "unchosen". Or am I wrong? Either way, that's my back-up plan! The teacher said the most important thing was to show the idea, and that the functionality didn't have to be perfect.

Answer (score 3):

**Radiobuttons**

I figured out the way to do the radiobuttons but they work only as far as one of them is focused.

```css
.radio {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    margin-left: 1em;
    padding-left: 1.5em;
}

.radio::before {
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 1em;
    height: 1em;
    border-radius: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
}

.radio:focus {
    outline: none;
}

.radio:focus::after {
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 0.5em;
    height: 0.5em;
    border-radius: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: black;
    left: 0.25em;
    top: 0.25em;
}
```

```html
<ul class="radio-group">
    <li tabindex="0" class="radio">Option 1</li>
    <li tabindex="0" class="radio">Option 2</li>
    <li tabindex="0" class="radio">Option 3</li>
</ul>
```

The key element here is the [`tabindex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/tabindex) in `<li>` items that makes them focusable.

> The tabindex global attribute indicates if its element can be focused, and if/where it participates in sequential keyboard navigation (usually with the Tab key, hence the name). It accepts an integer as a value, with different results depending on the integer's value: [...]

**Checkboxes**

I styled them but **I have no clue on how to make them work without JS**. *(Now they behave exactly like the radios.)*

```css
.check {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    margin-left: 1em;
    padding-left: 1.5em;
}

.check::before {
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 1em;
    height: 1em;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
}

.check:focus {
    outline: none;
}

.check:focus::after {
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    border-left: 3px solid black;
    border-bottom: 3px solid black;
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    width: 1em;
    height: 0.5em;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0.1em;
    top: -0.1em;
}
```

```html
<ul class="check-boxes">
    <li tabindex="0" class="check">Option 1</li>
    <li tabindex="0" class="check">Option 2</li>
    <li tabindex="0" class="check">Option 3</li>
</ul>
```

**Hint:** The only pure CSS thing that comes to my mind remotely similar of saving a state would be [CSS counters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Lists_and_Counters/Using_CSS_counters), but since you can't build a selector based on counter's value...

Answer (score 0):

To input data from users in HTML your only option is the input's tag. Take a look official documentation at:

https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_form_input_types.asp

Only with allowed tags your can't create radio-buttons and checkboxes.

Comment: I'm not allowed to use input! Is there another way?

Comment: You can't generate fields dynamically by native Javascript either?